# What is the best way to index 3d matrix with vectors?

Tags: python, indexing, jax

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
```

vectors and array are `jnp.array(dtype=jnp.int32)`

I have an array with shape [x, d, y] (3x3x3)

```
[[[0 0 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]],

[[0 0 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]],

[[0 0 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]]]
```

and vectors `x = [2 0 3], y = [ 2 0 1], d = [0 0 1]`

I want to have something like this by indexing but I tried and don't really know how, with jax.numpy.

```
[[[0 0 2],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]],

[[0 0 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [0 0 0]],

[[0 0 0],
 [0 3 0],
 [0 0 0]]]
```

Edit: I would like to specify that I wanted to put number from x with its index to the array but only when x > 0. I tried with boolean mask.
Something like this

```
mask = x > 0
array = array.at[mask, d, y].set(array[mask, d, y] + x)
```

Comment: I don't understand how you get that result from those inputs.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have `ndarray.at` or `ndarray.set`. Please add a [mre].

Comment: I am using jax.numpy I thought It would be the same

Comment: `np.arrays` are different: `jax` arrays are immutable and don't support index setters.

Comment: `array.at[mask, d[mask], y[mask]].set(x[mask])`, please add imports and clarify the type of your arrays to make the question answerable.

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a three-dimensional array, so you can index it with three arrays of indices. Since you want `d` and `y` to be associated with the second and third dimensions, you'll need to create another array of indices for the first dimension:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

arr = jnp.zeros((3, 3, 3), dtype='int32')
x = jnp.array([2, 0, 3])
y = jnp.array([2, 0, 1])
d = jnp.array([0, 0, 1])

i = jnp.arange(len(x))
mask = x > 0

out = arr.at[i[mask], d[mask], y[mask]].set(x[mask])
print(out)
# [[[0 0 2]
#   [0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0]]

#  [[0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0]]

#  [[0 0 0]
#   [0 3 0]
#   [0 0 0]]]
```

In this case the result will be the same whether or not you use the mask (i.e. `arr.at[i, d, y].set(x)` will give the same result) but because your question explicitly specified that you only want to use values `x > 0` I included it.